# SQL DB to Mobile service Transferring Scheme

Tags: azure, schema, transfer, azure-mobile-services

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Azure_Mobile_Services_-_Importing_data_from_Excel

using this link i done with all process but at the very last step, transferring schema i didn't get how exactly it transfer and at this sage i got error.

My Query

```
CREATE SCHEMA TimeTable;
ALTER SCHEMA kgce_db.TimeTable TRANSFER TimeTable;
```

1. In Mobile Services i have kgce>>TimeTable Where kgce is mobile service and TimeTable is DATA Table
2. In SQL DB i have kgce_db and i uploaded my EXCEL file in this DB "TimeTable.excel"

Answer (score 0):

1st line for creating new schema. in E.g TimeTable is my table in "kgce" Database i.e. kgce.TimeTable

2nd line "kgce" is my Azure SQL DB name,

```
CREATE SCHEMA TimeTable;
ALTER SCHEMA kgce TRANSFER kgce.TimeTable;
```

But by using this code i didn't get which i want. 
To move data from SQL DB Table to Mobile Service Table i used following steps
 1. Create one table "MobileServiceTT"
 2. Add same no of columns which is present in Excel file and now in SQL DB Table i.e. "SQLDB.Table" which we upload using link provided at starting.
 3. Open your SQL DB in Manage.
 4. Go to New Query
 5. Run Following Query

```
INSERT INTO MobileServiceTT (TimeAzure,Monday,Thuesday, Wednesday, Thursday,Friday) SELECT TIME,MON,TUE,WED,THURS,FRI FROM SQLDB.Table;
```

Syntax :

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (<columns>) SELECT <columns> FROM Table2 WHERE <CONDITION>;
```